# How to get an on object or an Exception from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-livedata

I have the following generic class:

```
public class DataOrException<T, E extends Exception> {
    public T data;
    public E exception;
}
```

And I'm getting from a Firebase authentication, a FirebaseUser object or an Exception:

```
MutableLiveData<DataOrException<FirebaseUser, Exception>> signIn(String email, String password) {
    MutableLiveData<DataOrException<FirebaseUser, Exception>> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
            liveData.setValue(firebaseUser);
        } else {
            liveData.setValue(authTask.getException());
        }
    });
    return liveData;
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
setValue(com.example.DataOrException<com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser, java.lang.Exception>)
in MutableLiveData cannot be applied to (java.lang.Exception)
```

What should I pass to setValue() so it cannot complain anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MutableLiveData expects a value of type `DataOrException<FirebaseUser, Exception>`, so you will need to construct one and pass it.

```
DataOrException<FirebaseUser, Exception> value = new DataOrException<>()
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    value.data = auth.getCurrentUser();
} else {
    value.exception = authTask.getException();
}
liveData.setValue(value);
```

Comment: That was the only thing that was missing from one of your videos.